# Does the google+ API have a way to get the feeds of the people I follow?

Tags: google-plus

In the facebook and twitter APIs, there's a way to get posts from all the people I follow, is there a way to do this with Google+? If there isn't, where can I suggest it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ API currently does not provide a way to list people from your circles.

You can retrieve people in other ways. Try retrieving people by userId, through a search, or by activity using the [people methods](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people). With each userId you can retrieve posts using [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list).

Feature requests and issues can be reported and starred here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/